# Rails 3 Installation Hangs at Gem Builder with "unable to convert "\xF1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, builder

I followed this tutorial http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/23/install-rails-ruby-mac to install Ruby on Rails on Mac OS X (Lion 10.7).

Everything went fine until I installed Rails with rvm (v. 1.6) when I received the following messages:

```
Installing RDoc documentation for builder-3.0.0...
unable to convert "\xF1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for README, skipping
unable to convert "\xF1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for README.rdoc, skipping**
```

(Builder version succesfully installed 2.1.2)

and

```
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.0.9...
file 'lib' not found
```

(Rails version succesfully installed 3.0.9)

I did some research but couldn't find a solution. It looks like I am not the only one to having this problem.

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RubyGems just couldn't change the encoding for the README. Rails should work perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I now understand (= discovered that there are files conversions during ROR installation).