# Gem install rails can't finish

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Had a really rough day with Ruby so far...

Using RVM I'm trying to just install rails into a new gemset but running gem install rails hangs toward the end and never returns control back to the user.

It gets to this point and dies:

```
Installing RDoc documentation for activesupport-3.1.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for builder-3.0.0...
unable to convert "\xF1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for README, skipping
unable to convert "\xF1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for README.rdoc, skipping
```

After that it just hangs forever and the only way to get out is to ctrl-C and interrupt the process. I've tried gem install rails and gem install rails -v 3.1.0. Both do the same thing.

Comment: On what OS? (Can always try --no-rdoc --no-ri, with the obvious side-effects.)

Comment: Same as this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858709/rails-3-installation-gem-builder-unable-to-convert-xf1-from-ascii-8bit-to

Comment: OSX Snow Leopard, i'll try the no doc approach. *edit* using --no-rdoc and --no-ri worked. thanks!

Answer (score 11):

i had the same problem some minutes ago, the install stuck at the same point, then got killed but it seemed to be installed (doing a gem search rails it found the installed gem).
So i tried with a

```
gem update
gem uninstall rails
gem install rails
```

and it worked (at least it finished without errors.. it's my first test with RoR)

Comment: I tried this and it did not work for me. I'm on a Mac running Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

With "gem update" I found some errors in "make "DESTDIR=" clean (not found)" and I did not figure out the reason for that.
Using "gem uninstall rails", it gives me that rails is not alreadty installed.
And I can't install rails typing "gem install rails".

Comment: Here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html you can find much information about the installation of Rails!

Comment: I found a step by step guide at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.
It is easy to follow: first, you have to install ruby, after sqlite3 and node and yarn. So easily you can install rails using 'gem install rails'. It worked pretty fine to me. I hope it helps!